# Data frames and is.nan()

Tags: r

I was using `sum(is.na(my.df))` to check whether my data frame contained any NAs, which worked as I expected, but `sum(is.nan(my.df))` did not work as I expected.

```
> my.df <- data.frame(a=c(1, 2, 3), b=c(5, NA, NaN))
> my.df
  a   b
1 1   5
2 2  NA
3 3 NaN
> is.na(my.df)
         a     b
[1,] FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE  TRUE
[3,] FALSE  TRUE
> is.nan(my.df)
    a     b 
FALSE FALSE 
> sum(is.na(my.df))
[1] 2
> sum(is.nan(my.df))
[1] 0
```

Oh dear.
Is there a reason for the inconsistency in behaviour? Is it for a lack of implementation, or is it intentional? What does the return value of `is.nan(my.df)` signify? Is there a good reason not to use `is.nan()` on a whole data frame?

In the documentation for `is.na( )` and `is.nan( )`, the argument types seem the same (although they don't specifically list data frames):

`is.na()`:   x  R object to be tested: the default methods handle atomic vectors, lists and pairlists.
`is.nan()`: x  R object to be tested: the default methods handle atomic vectors, lists and pairlists.

Comment: no ideas as to why the apparent inconsistency, but for an element by element comparison of `is.nan`, try `apply(my.df, c(1,2), is.nan)`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From `?is.nan`:

```
All elements of logical,integer and raw vectors are considered not to be NaN, and
elements of lists and pairlists are also unless the element is a length-one numeric
or complex vector whose single element is NaN.
```

The columns of a data frame are technically "elements of a list", so `is.nan(df)` returns a vector with length equal to the number of columns of the data frame, which is `TRUE` only if the column consists of a single `NaN` element:

```
> is.nan(data.frame(a=NaN,b=NA,c=1))
    a     b     c 
 TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

If you want behavior matching that of `is.na`, use `apply`:

```
sum(apply(my.df,2,is.nan))
```

The answer is 1 rather than 2 because `is.nan(NA)` is `FALSE` ...

**edit**: alternatively, you can just turn the data frame into a matrix:

```
 sum(is.nan(as.matrix(my.df)))
```

**update**: this behaviour changed shortly (two months) after the question was asked, in R version 2.14 (October 2011): from the [NEWS file](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2011/000544.html),

> o The default methods for is.finite(), is.infinite() and is.nan() now signal an error if their argument is not an atomic vector.

Comment: I'm curious why it would be implemented that way. Any idea what the common use case being targeted is?

Comment: Not really. I think of `is.na` as a more general description of data and `is.nan` as a specific detector of numerical weirdness. You'd probably have to ask R-core what they were thinking ...

Comment: When running 
      `is.nan(data.frame(a=NaN,b=NA,c=1))` I get
`Error in is.nan(data.frame(a = NaN, b = NA, c = 1)) : 
  default method not implemented for type 'list'` Puzzled. @Ben Bolker

Answer (score 8):

The `is.nan` function does not work with lists for some odd reason. Why it differs from `is.na` is beyond me and appears to be a language design issue. However, there is a simple solution:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1, 2, 3), b=c(5, NA, NaN)) 
df <- data.frame(sapply(df, function(x) ifelse(is.nan(x), NA, x)))
df
  a  b
1 1  5
2 2 NA
3 3 NA
```

Comment: Hi @Adam It resets the index of the resulting df dataframe. is there any way to retain the index as well