# Why is there inconsistency between is.na() and is.nan() for matrices

Tags: r, matrix, subset, nan, na

Reproducible example:

```
# test data with NaN and NA values
df <- data.frame(
  v1 = c(1, 2, 3),
  v2 = c(NaN, 4, 5),
  v3 = c(6, NA, 7)
)

# extract NA values: works
df[is.na(df)]

# extract NaN values: fails!
is.nan(df)

# The long way to do that...
df[sapply(df, is.nan)]
```

The second solution works fine. But why does the 1st not work when it does for `is.na`?

Comment: `is.nan` works on `vector` and not on `data.frame` or `matrix`

Comment: Any ideas why @akrun?

Comment: You can check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031127/data-frames-and-is-nan) for some ideas and also [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5686/what-is-the-difference-between-nan-and-na)

Comment: Because there is no `is.nan` method for data.frames.